# Designing A Register File For A MIPS Processor Using VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I'm in the process of designing a MIPS processor using VHDL. In the write operation I'm having errors which I can't really understand its content. I already have designed a MUX 32*1 *,* Decoder *5**32 & Flopr.

The RegFile

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use work.Project_Package.ALL;

entity Reg is
    Port ( read_sel1 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           read_sel2 : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           write_sel : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           write_ena : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           write_data : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           data1 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           data2 : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end Reg;

architecture Behavioral of Reg is

--Signal Declaration
signal decoder_output: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
signal reset_flopr: STD_LOGIC := '0';
type reg_type is array (0 to 31 ) of std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
signal reg_outputs: reg_type;

begin

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------Write Implementation-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

--Write Decoder
decoder1: Decoder_5x32 port map (read_sel1,decoder_output);

--Registers
reg_gen : for i in 0 to 31 generate
  reg: Flopr port map (clk, reset_flopr, write_ena AND decoder_output(i), write_data, reg_outputs(i));
end generate reg_gen;


end Behavioral;
```

Package:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

package Project_Package is

--Flopr Implementation
component Flopr GENERIC(n:integer);
     Port ( CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RST : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Load : in STD_LOGIC;
           D : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 downto 0);
           Q : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (n-1 downto 0));
end component;

--Decoder Implementation
component Decoder_5x32
    Port ( Selector : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           Data_Out : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end component;

--MUX Implementation
component MUX_32x1
    Port ( Data_In : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           Selector : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
           Data_Out : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

end Project_Package;
```

Errors:

Line 35: Formal  has no actual or default value.

Comment: You need an input on `entity Reg` for RST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VHDL reserved word `array` can only be used for type declarations, not object declarations (`variable`, `signal`, `constant`). Hence you first need to declare an array type to hold your `reg_outputs`:

eg.

```vhdl
type reg_array_t is array (0 to 31) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

signal reg_outputs : reg_array_t := (others => (others => '0'));
```

You have also used a procedural `for` loop outside of a procedural region (eg. `process`, `function`, `procedure`). Here, you need to use a generate loop:

```vhdl
reg_gen : for i in 0 to 31 generate
  ...
end generate reg_gen;
```

Comment: That helps a lot thank you
but there is still an error
Line 35: Syntax error near ":".

Comment: before VHDL 2008, logical expressions are not allowed in port maps.

Comment: Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: either use VHDL 2008 or create a temporary signal and connect that in the port map.